# How can I bottom-align this btn-group using only css?

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have a sequence of div's that I turned into 2-columns which look like this:

[image]

I want to bottom-align the PDF/XML button group so it looks like this:

[image]

This is what the html looks like:

```
<div class="media-list">
  <div class="article-summary media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h3 class="media-heading">
        <a href="">
           Boosting SRL for Recommendation Systems
        </a>
      </h3>
      <div class="meta">
        <div class="authors">
          Kaushik Roy
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          PDF
        </a>
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          XML
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="article-summary media">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="article-summary media">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And if this is helpful, here's a snippet of css that I made to make these div's into 2-columns:

```
.media {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.media:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change the html. Think of this like a wordpress site where you have to use their html template and only allowed to make css changes.

What do you recommend I do?

Comment: Have you tried adding an inline style to the div `authors`? `<div class="authors" style="min-height: XXXpx;">` That is what I would do, It isn't pretty, and you could just add another class, but it does get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use flex box

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.media-list{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.media {
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:2em;
  width: 50%;
  flex:1 auto;
}
.media-body{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
.media-body > .meta{
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="media-list">
  <div class="article-summary media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h3 class="media-heading">
        <a href="">
           Boosting SRL for Recommendation Systems
        </a>
      </h3>
      <div class="meta">
        <div class="authors">
          Kaushik Roy
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          PDF
        </a>
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          XML
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="article-summary media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h3 class="media-heading">
        <a href="">
           ADE from EHR data
        </a>
      </h3>
      <div class="meta">
        <div class="authors">
          Kaushik Roy
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          PDF
        </a>
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          XML
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="article-summary media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h3 class="media-heading">
        <a href="">
           SLR with Hidden Data
        </a>
      </h3>
      <div class="meta">
        <div class="authors">
          Kaushik Roy
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          PDF
        </a>
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          XML
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="article-summary media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h3 class="media-heading">
        <a href="">
           Scholarly Associations and the Economic Viability of Open Access Publishing
        </a>
      </h3>
      <div class="meta">
        <div class="authors">
          Kaushik Roy
          Kaushik Roy
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          PDF
        </a>
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          XML
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This elegant solution worked beautifully. Thank you! You're awesome!

Comment: I will look into flexbox, but can you give me a brief explanation of why this worked?

Comment: @kane One useful property of flexbox items (*under same container*) is that they share the same height per line (*the tallest one*). Inside each we set again the  `.media-body` to also be `display:flex` (*a new flex box*) but this time vertical, and set the middle element (*`.meta`*) to occupy as much space as possible. (*the other elements expand according to their contents*) so it will push the `.button-group` to the bottom.

Comment: That was an elegant explanation to an elegant solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="article-summary media">
   <div class="media-body">
      <h3 class="media-heading">
        <a href="">
           Boosting SRL for Recommendation Systems
        </a>
      </h3>
      <div class="meta" style="min-height: XXXpx;">
        <div class="authors">
          Kaushik Roy
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          PDF
        </a>
        <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
          XML
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

I think this is the easiest way. OR you could add a height to the `article-summary-media` DIV and then position the `btn-group` near the bottom?

Comment: I tried the min-height on .authors, but it just pushes the button group down. They're still not aligned

Comment: might need an `!important` in the css?

Comment: Also tried min-height on .article-summary.media, and that just expands the bottom margin of each cell, but the button group doesn't move at all

Comment: Don't think !important is the problem. The css is being applied. It's just not doing the right thing

Comment: oh! I might have made a mistake. Is it actually the `meta` div?

Comment: Well, usually the best way to get these to bottom align is using that technique. I noticed after reviewing the code that `authors` is INSIDE `meta` SO no guess, just a mistake.

Comment: what about `flexbox` ? you can align items in any way you want

Answer (score 0):

You can either use flexbox **or** (in pseudo code)...

Make adjacent columns equal height (using a js plugin like matchHeight.js)

Set `article-summary` to `position: relative`.

Make your button group position absolute at the bottom with `bottom: 0`.

Adjust `padding-bottom` of `article-summary` so that the button group doesn't overlap content.